# Problem with Combobox binding to ObservableCollection in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox, binding

I have a little problem and I don't know how to fix it.
In my View I have a combobox, that should be able to display the property "Name" of the ObservableCollection "Phases". I already tried to show a single "Name-property" without a Datatemplate and it worked. I think I messed something up with the binding in the DataTemplate. What is wrong? Can you help me?

Here is my View:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Phases}"
              SelectedItem=""
              Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="50,20">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Here my ObservableCollection:

```
public ObservableCollection<PhaseViewModel> Phases
    {
        get;
    }
```

And here the property inside Phases:

```
    public string Name
    {
        get { return myName; }
        set { myName = value;}
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear, *what is* the problem. Could you give more details?

Comment: The combobox is empty when I use the DataTemplate but when I use the code at the end it displays only one name and not the list of names      <ComboBox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
 </ComboBox>

Comment: Are there any binding errors in Output window? Looks like `ComboBox` has another DataContext, than you expect.

Comment: Yes this error shows up: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Phases' property not found on 'object' ''ObservableCollection`1' (HashCode=30123835)'. BindingExpression:Path=Phases; DataItem='ObservableCollection`1' (HashCode=30123835); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: So, `ComboBox.DataContext` is `ObservableCollection`. If this is OK, just rewrite `ItemsSource` binding expression like this: `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding }"`

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome )